# onFling and LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, onfling

My Linear Layout: `main_linear_layout` contains four Linear Layouts: `ll1` `ll2` `ll3` `ll4`. Each `LinearLayout` contains `Buttons`. I am trying to implement the onFling method on `main_linear_layout`. I want to be able to swipe anywhere on the Layout of `Buttons` and call an action.

Currently I am able to swipe anywhere on the screen except for the Layout of Buttons. I tried using the following code to fix the problem:

```
swipeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);
//swipeLayout is the main Layout that contains 4 other linear layouts

swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

But I am still not able to swipe on the Layout of `Buttons`. Does anybody know why this is? Is there something else I need to implement? Am I supposed to implement an `OnTouchListener` to every Linear Layout inside the main Linear Layout? Or to every `Button` in each Layout?

And in the `xml` I added a bunch of code to the main Linear Layout:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:longClickable="true"
```

But this did not work either. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `LinearLayout`, and then more layouts inside of that, and then buttons on those as you say you do, then this is functioning as intended.

You're only adding the listener to the outside layout...so of course, it'll only trigger when you slide on it. By sliding on the other layouts, or even the buttons, the slide event doesn't even get to that listener, because it is consumed.

You'd need to add the listener to each element that you want to be checking for.

One way to do this is to create an array of your buttons and do it all at once:

```
private Button button1;
private Button button2; 
....
private Button button10;

...
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ...
    button10 = findViewById(R.id.button10);
    OnClickListener onCL = new OnClickListener . . . //do all of your creation here
    Button[] buttons = {button1, button2, . . . , button10};
    for(Button b : buttons) {
        b.setOnClickListener(onCL);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have 20 Buttons in four layouts, is there a way I can make one Listener that will effect the entire Layout, or do I need to repeat the same code 20 times?

Comment: @user2456977 see my response - I've added an ~easy way to do it. Just create an array, then look through the buttons.

Comment: I did not have a chance to check the answer yet. Once I check I will select an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason the ll1,ll2,ll3,ll4 don't pick up on touch events is because the parent linear layout receives the motion event and it doesn't propagate further.

Why do you need a touch event listener on the main linear layout? Do you want the sub layouts to all fling together?

If you want the other layouts to pick up on the touch event return false on the touch listener

```
swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
});
```

Or you could create 4 GestureDetectors and pass the event to the right one depending on which view was pressed

```
swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.ll1:

        gesture1.ontouchEvent(e);
        break;

    case R.id.ll2:

        gesture1.ontouchEvent(e);
        break;
    }
    //etc


    return false;
}
});
```